# Celery 4.2.1 (windowlicker) not throwing exception in Linux

Tags: python, rest, ubuntu, flask, celery

In local environment [windows], celery seems to be working fine when the following is executed:

```
try:
    from .redis_repo import redis_store
except ImportError:
    from redis_repo import redis_store
```

This is point of entry for my celery task, in local environment its working because try catch seems to working fine. But in linux environment it doesn't .

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Eventually i figured it out, It was throwing an exception its just that it was incorrect. So as a fix, I added SystemError.